# Google Analytics Report For Weekdays Only

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to create a custom report in Google Analytics that will measure weekday performance only over a period of time ie week 01 (Monday to Friday) verses week 02 (Monday to Friday).

Is this possible and if so how.

Answer (score 6):

This is entirely possible. Assuming you are running Google Analytics Version 5 (the new interface):

```
1. Go to "Custom Reports" (top navigation)
2. Click on "+New Custom Report"
3. And set the following:
 a. +add metric: Entrances, Bounces, Unique Visitors, Pageviews, Avg. Time on Page, Avg. Time on Site
 b. +add dimension: Day of Week, Page Title, Visitor Type, City, and whatever you like
4. Enter filters:
 a. Exclude "Day of Week" Exact 0 (that's Sunday)
 b. Exclude "Day of Week" Exact 6 (that's Saturday)
```

Or for easy reference I have already set it up and shared:
[Performance Weekdays: Click me](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/crPermalink?data=AH4sIAAAAAAAAAHWPwUrDQBCGs1FEFpEYFdfFQ9ibPUhEUfDkQfAkFhra8xqnZTDNht1JJI_ga7QP4Cua6GGrmOv3_TPzT2x4EAt-NAY7N3apyxySGcDbq25dFKhDXeqiJczdBZRke-1GZ3wDd8HneT8Rs1SwhA3am96mTH6GfPsyvbrttg_eXe18hHzN-uB1KiO-9wRkMU8eramrgVrqwMMXU3-jE4_IkC6m6JCMdZsLKr2ABuHdqVMPdbMYd_yhtprQlEr8UhNwrqMZLmE0k_-9q-7lnxMZUgHqXB573Py0ydoKVCT3vciR2rtdEQgmQrH1BYtDXY2jAQAA)

Here's a screenshot of a custom report Google Analytics (as of January 2017) with the configuration to show only weekday data:

[image: custom Google analytics report, configuration options for showing only weekday data]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way you can do it is by assigning custom variables to visits that happen between Monday and Friday with JavaScript, and disable them on weekends.

Then you can create a segment (and/or a custom report) based on that custom variable value.

Search for setCustomVar in Google to find out more:

```
_setCustomVar(index, name, value, opt_scope);
```

*Please note that I'm not sure if the report will count weekends as days with zero visits and decrease your metrics. Maybe someone else can help or you can test it in the next two weeks.*